# cq5, NoClassDefFoundError for SyndFeedImpl when using it within a OSGi environment

Tags: rss, osgi, noclassdeffounderror, aem, osgi-bundle

Getting a NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeedImpl when trying to use rome 1.0 to create a rss feed.

I've tried "-Drome.pluginmanager.useloadclass=true" setting, both on true and false with no luck.

Any reason why the rome bundle will successfully load but can't be used, without getting a noclassdeffound?

Comment: this happens when SyndFeedImpl was found but a dependency of it was not. http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/What_is_the_difference_between_ClassNotFoundException_and_NoClassDefFoundError%3F
looking at the rome pom, it seems they embed all their dependencies in the bundle (besides jdom and junit). do you have any the full stack trace?

Comment: is jdom osgi compatible?

Comment: stacktrace? and setup? Way too little information to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here can be resolved by adding the following to your pom.xml if using the Maven Bundle plugin:

```
<Import-Package>!com.sun.syndication.*, *</Import-Package>
```

See here: [Maven Bundle Plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html)

Or add something similar to your MANIFEST.MF file for your OSGi bundle if you aren't using Maven to build your bundle.

```
Import-Package: !com.sun.syndication.*, *
```

We're successfully using an OSGi-ified version of ROME on a project.

Comment: None of those worked for me. In the end we went with creating the rss feed via JSP and did not use Rome.